# Как проверить запущено ли какое-то определённое приложение?

Tags: java

Добрый день, как можно программно проверить запущено ли какое-то определённое приложение, ОС Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean checkPPOpen(String name) throws IOException {
    String line;
    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.contains(name)) {
            continue;
        }
        return true;
    }
    reader.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ложная реакция на test.exe при запущенном maintest.exe

Comment: а когда находим совпадение reader закрывать не обязательно?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov в данной ситуации лучше всего обернуть в try-with-resources

Comment: @I.Perevoz я про это знаю, это был тонкий намек автору что у него некорректный код

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov данный ресурс вроде бы не для тонких намеков. Если есть что посоветовать, ткните носом куда надо.

Comment: @I.Perevoz тонкий в кавычках

Answer (score 1):

Адаптация ответа: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950/3347171/

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] s) {
    try {
      String line;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
      BufferedReader input =
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         // Тут будет строка вида:
         // tasklist.exe        1234 Console 1 414я444 ??
         // то есть то, что выводит tasklist.exe в консоли.
         // Парсите строку и вытягиваете то, что вам нужно.
         System.out.println(line); 
      }
      input.close();
   } catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: Укажите источник откуда брали материал - это первое. Второе - ТС просил проверку по конкретному процессу, но никак не список

Comment: @GenCloud ссылку на источник добавил. По второму - уже придирка.

Comment: почему де придирка, лишь констатация факта

Comment: @GenCloud считаю в формате сайта важно дать идею решения, а не законченное приложение. Например из условия задачи не ясно в каком виде будет поступать информация. Поэтому я и привел решение в таком виде, а реализацию парсинга оставил на выбор ТС. Если уж так оценивать то и ваш ответ выдаст ошибочный результат в некоторых случаях. Поэтому я и считаю вторую часть вашего комментария придиркой.

Comment: @GreyGoblin не подскажите как можно в режиме онлайн контролировать процесс а не вызывать постоянно метод ?

Comment: @VargSieg подписаться на сообщения о изменениях состояния нужной вам задачи системы вряд ли получится. Во всяком случае у меня нет информации что ОС вещает глобально или адресно о появлении/завершении процесса. А что вам не нравится в цикличном опросе? Создайте поток-демон который раз в какое-то время будет опрашивать состояние процесса и оповещать подписчиков о изменении. Задача в целом не сложная.

Comment: @GreyGoblin да нравиться это первое о чём подумал, но потом, а не костыль ли это и может есть более красивый вариант.

Comment: @VargSieg взгляните на задачу в целом. Может костылем является сама необходимость отслеживания состояния процесса в системе и от этого можно как-нибудь отказаться.